# Issue with Datetime in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am importing some data from excel to db, the issue is I want to set the specific default value like `00/00/0000` to `datetime` column when there is no date available from the Excel file.

The `getdate()` sets the date to current one, but I want to set to a specific date, is it possible to achieve something like this.

Comment: probably yes. Can you be more specific on how you are doing the import?

Comment: i want to check if that field is empty , if yes then set that field to specific date

Comment: How are you importing - using a sql script?

Comment: i am using http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/58/Exporting-data-to-a-CSV-tab-delimited-or-other-text-format

Comment: @MrA: that link is about exporting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can set a default value - but be aware: `DATETIME` has a valid range from `1/1/1753` through `12/31/9999` - so setting it to `0/0/0000` will **NOT** be a valid `DATETIME` value!

If you need such a value - use either `DATETIME2` in SQL Server 2008 (range is from `1/1/0001` through `12/31/9999`) - or use `DATE` (without any time - same range as `DATETIME2`)

Or: just make your `DATETIME/DATETIME2/DATE` column nullable and insert `NULL` when no date is present - that would be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you use bcp or BULK INSERT or SQLBulkCopy, then you have the option of keeping NULLs.
If you don't, then you get the default for the column.

See ["Keeping Nulls or Using Default Values During Bulk Import"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx%22) on MSDN

If you can't (say because you get empty string not NULL) then you can use a a staging table first, then load the data from that with a combination of NULLID, ISNULL and CASE. Or use a trigger, but this will slow you down more so than doing the load in 2 steps

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are performing your import, but if you wish to check whether a value is NULL and set it to a defined value then you can use the SQL `IsNull(a,b)` where a is the value to check and b is the value to return.

```
insert into [dbo].[tblSomeTable] 
  set [someField] = IsNull(@thisValueMayBeNull, thisValueIfNull)
```

Probably not a good example but should point you in the right direction.

Or once your data has been imported you could run an update script to replace all `NULL` dates with a fixed value;

Or you could set the date field in the database to `NOT NULL` and give it a defaut value.